# Last day of most recent financial quarter in Snowflake

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a simple way to return the last day of the most recent quarter in Snowflake?

We use financial quarters with last days being: Jan. 31, Apr. 30, July 31, Oct. 31

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was not sure if you want the last day of current quarter or prior quarter, but this should be enough to get where you want to go:

```
SELECT current_date today,
    date_trunc('quarter', today) as cur_qrt,
    dateadd('day', -1, cur_qrt) as last_day_of_prior_qrt,
    dateadd('day', -1, dateadd('quarter', 1, cur_qrt)) as last_day_of_current_qrt;
```

| TODAY | CUR_QRT | LAST_DAY_OF_PRIOR_QRT | LAST_DAY_OF_CURRENT_QRT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-19 | 2022-01-01 | 2021-12-31 | 2022-03-31 |

Thus last day of prior quarter for any `day` is:

```
dateadd('day', -1, date_trunc('quarter', DAY)) as last_day_of_prior_qrt,
```

Hmm, how you framed the question, I don't see how your dates are what you want.. BUT if they are then that is good.

```
SELECT 
    to_date(column1) as day,
    IFF( extract(month, day) in (1, 4, 7, 10),
        add_months(dateadd('day', -1, date_trunc('quarter', day)), -2),
        add_months(dateadd('day', -1, date_trunc('quarter', day)), 1) 
    ) as last_day_of_prior_qrt,
    date_trunc('quarter', day) as cur_qrt,
    dateadd('day', -1, date_trunc('quarter', day)) as sim_sqt
 from values 
    ('2021-01-04'),('2021-02-04'),('2021-03-04'),('2021-04-04'),('2021-05-04'),('2021-06-04'),('2021-07-04'),('2021-08-04');
```

gives:

| DAY | LAST_DAY_OF_PRIOR_QRT | CUR_QRT | SIM_SQT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-04 | 2020-10-31 | 2021-01-01 | 2020-12-31 |
| 2021-02-04 | 2021-01-31 | 2021-01-01 | 2020-12-31 |
| 2021-03-04 | 2021-01-31 | 2021-01-01 | 2020-12-31 |
| 2021-04-04 | 2021-01-31 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-03-31 |
| 2021-05-04 | 2021-04-30 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-03-31 |
| 2021-06-04 | 2021-04-30 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-03-31 |
| 2021-07-04 | 2021-04-30 | 2021-07-01 | 2021-06-30 |
| 2021-08-04 | 2021-07-31 | 2021-07-01 | 2021-06-30 |

and given 4th Jan 2021 is in the 2021 Q1 I don't see how the "prior" quarter id 2020 Q3 and thus the last day of is `2020-10-31`, But again if that is the results you want..

Comment: Thanks! Looking for last day of prior quarter. I'm going to see if I can modify this to accommodate the following fiscal quarter end dates:

Jan. 31, Apr. 30, July 31, Oct. 31

Comment: This slight modification returns the results I need. Thanks again for the help.


```SELECT
CASE WHEN extract(month, current_date()) in (1, 4, 7, 10)
THEN add_months(dateadd('day', -1, date_trunc('quarter', current_date())), -2) 
ELSE add_months(dateadd('day', -1, date_trunc('quarter', current_date())), 1) end as last_day_of_prior_qrt```

Comment: @tennis_fan89 I made another update, swapped `CASE WHEN` for `IFF` but also your results feel strange to me.

Comment: I know, it's a bit confusing, but it's the results I need. This client has their fiscal quarters setup that way. 

What's the reason for swapping CASE WHEN for IFF? Performance improvements?

Comment: @tennis_fan89 reason for `IFF` "smaller code" they are "that same code" if you write the SQL with the CASE with only 2 branches (WHEN/ELSE) and there is a compile error, the message comes back error in IFF, so the SQL compiler see then as "the same". There is an argument "use the ANSI SQL" but I don't buy that, I believe you should use the smallest code that is the most explicit about what you want. Which is why I don't like implicit type casts in queries, "was it meant" or "is it a typo".

Comment: Gotcha. thanks for the explanation! I appreciate your help!